# Technique for conditional statements

Tags: filemaker

I'm developing something in a Database System and I'm stuck on what I assume is a simple programming solution. Any pseudo-code / logic is greatly appreciated. This is a boiled version of the scenario:

```
"You have a list of N items with traits like below:

item_Type = (Pipe, Rod, Tube)
cut_Size = a user-inputted number
finish = (#3, #8, 2B)
sub_Type = Pipe (Schedule 40, Schedule 20) / Rod (Square, Rectangular,       Round) / Tube (Square, Rectangular, Round) 
cut_Dims = *THERE'S HUNDREDS OF THESE*

Where item number 1 has traits like item_Type1, cut_Size1, etc and item N has traits like item_TypeN, cut_SizeN, etc. 


You have to filter items by all of their traits and create a counter that counts and accumulates their cut_Sizes"
```

Basically there's thousands of combinations for different counters here.

So right away I (amateurishly) started a series of If statements that began with the type itself (If (item_Type1 = "Rod")) { Etc...} and started filtering with more and more if statements. The key thing here is that I could easily make 3 If Statements for the "item_Types" because there's literally 3 of them.

My problem lies with implementing this technique with a trait that has hundreds and hundreds of variations, like "cut_Dims"

Let me know if that wasn't clear enough or if you need more information.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

For multiple conditions, use the Case function. You can do combinations of Case and the ExecuteSQL function if you can’t get a narrow enough result with the Case function alone.